# Python Programming in a for loop with lists involved

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
import random   #Imports the random module

name = input("Enter your first name: ")   #Prompts the user to input their first name

name = name.capitalize()    #Capitalizes their first name

randomPhrase = ''   #For the random phrase to start out with being in a string

phrase = input("Enter a phrase containing characters a-z and/or 0-9: ")  #Prompts the user to input a phrase

phrase = phrase.lower() #automatically lowercases all characters in the phrase

phraseLength = len(phrase)  #Gets the length of the phrase the user inputs

phrase = [phrase]   #Converts phrase to a list

'print(phraseLength)' #This is to test to see if it correctly gets how long the phrase is

allowedChars = [' ', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
                'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4',
                '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']  #This will be the alphabet and numbers, which is allowed to be in the phrase

""""""
for x in phrase:    #This will go for however long the phrase is

    if x in allowedChars:   #This will tell if the user input phrase contains characters from alloweChars

        print("It works")   #Outputs this Works, mainly for testing reasons

    if x not in allowedChars:   #This will tell if the phrase does not contain any characters from allowedChars

        phrase = input("Enter another phrase: ")    #If the user doesn't have any chars from allowedChars, they input a new phrase


for i in range(0, phraseLength):    #This is to generate a random phrase that is the same length as the user phrase

    randomPhrase = randomPhrase + random.choice(allowedChars)   #Continually adds a new character from allowedChars to the randomPhrase

print(randomPhrase) #Spits out a random phrase the length of the phrase from the user
```

in the first for loop, i have two if statements, and if the user inputs any number into their first phrase, it jumps straight to the second if statement even though it is in the list of allowed characters. I am not sure why that keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to do it.

```
import string
allowedChars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + ' ' # 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 '
randomPhrase = ''
name = input("Enter your first name: ")
name = name.capitalize()    #Capitalizes their first name
phrase = input("Enter a phrase containing characters a-z and/or 0-9: ")  #Prompts the user to input a phrase
while not phrase.replace(' ', '').isalnum():
    phrase = input("Enter another phrase: ")
for i in range(len(phrase)):    #This is to generate a random phrase that is the same length as the user phrase
    randomPhrase += random.choice(allowedChars)   #Continually adds a new character from allowedChars to the randomPhrase
print(randomPhrase)
```

String `.isalnum()` method checks whether the string contains only alphanumeric characters. I've used `phrase.replace(' ', '')` to delete spaces because they are allowed in your code. The `while not phrase.replace(' ', '').isalnum()` loop will run until someone insert a properly formated phrase.

Comment: As long as you're improving the loop, you could reduce it to a genexpr and a `''.join` to save slow explicit looping (and to avoid Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm issues with repeated string concatenation): `randomPhrase = ''.join(random.choice(allowedChars) for _ in enumerate(phrase))`

Comment: Yes, I know I could do that, but tried to avoid that, because he might not know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this code is not doing what you think it is:

```
for x in phrase:    #This will go for however long the phrase is
    if x in allowedChars:   #This will tell if ...
```

You can see what I mean by this, by adding this print code to that for loop:

```
print("x = {}".format(x))
```

The output produced will be the entire string and not the individual characters.

So the first step to fixing your code would be to change this line:

```
phrase = [phrase]   #Converts phrase to a list
```

To this:

```
phrase = list(phrase)   #Converts phrase to a list
```

Now at least that for loop will loop over the characters of the string.

Answer (score 0):

`phrase = [phrase]` is not doing what you think. It's making a single element `list` with the complete phrase as its single element, not a `list` of the individual characters.

This means the first `x` is the complete `phrase`; it's not just if the user enters a number, it's literally any input longer than one character long that will fail the test (because none of the entries in `allowed` are longer than length 1).

You probably meant to do `phrase = list(phrase)` which would return a `list` of the individual characters. But you don't need to do that; `str` are already iterables of their characters (that's why the `list` constructor can accept `str`), and you're not mutating `phrase`, so just omit the conversion entirely and iterate the original string.

As the other answer notes, this is a slow, terrible way to do this, but I wanted you to understand *why* this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the line:

phrase = [phrase]

what you want to do do convert phrase to a list is

phrase = list(phrase)

it works when I run it this way, though it prints "it works" a bunch of times :)

Comment: *what you want to do to convert phrase to a list